# Is there a way to replace the last letter of a line by a symbol everytime "break-word" is applied?

Tags: html, css

The css property `word-break: break-word;` breaks a word to avoid an overflow. Is there any way to add a sign like "-" at the end of a line everytime break-word is applied? That would really help to indicate that a word was broken and would enhance readability.

Thats how break-word works by default:

[image]

I would like it to replace the last letter of the line and put in the symbol "-" in instead, so it would look like this everytime break-word is applied.

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the css property called `hyphens`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens

Answer (score 0):

You can use hyphens property. 
The compatibility is also good. https://caniuse.com/#search=hyphens

```
.class{ hyphens: auto;}
```

Comment: Only if the algorithm recognises the word *should* be hypenated though.